# Writing functional code, example of find function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to convert the following function according to FP paradigm:

```
def findByEmail(email: String): User = {
   val result = jdbc.find("select * from user where email..")
   return result;
}
```

My first attempt is the following one:

```
def findByEmail(email: String): Either[String, Option[User]] = {
   try {
      val result = jdbc.find("select * from user where email..")
   } catch (Exception e) {
      return Left(e.getMessage())
   }

   if (result == null) return Right(None)

   Right(result)
}
```

The thing which I do not like is the try which catches all exceptions. Is there any good practice for such things? Is there any better data type rather than String for the left side of either? Is it ok to use the Exception class there?

Comment: That doesn't really have to do with FP for one. You should almost never catch all `Exception`s.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your first example doesn't catch exceptions at all, where your second does. Are you really asking how to flow exceptions?

Comment: You should never catch all exceptions but on the other hand exceptions break RT and are not type safe, so how can I force the caller of my API to handle them?

Comment: You use `Try(jdbc)` or you could go all the way: https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie

Comment: May I ask, how your last statement works "Right(result)". I would say that you haven't any access to "result" because the scope is inside the try. Or do I have any misconceptions about scopes? I know that it's off-topic, regarding to the question but thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to flow a `Try[User]` instead. Then, the caller can match on `Success[A]` or `Failure[Throwable]`:

```
def findByEmail(email: String): Try[User] = Try { jdbc.find("select * from user where email..") }
```

And then you force the caller to either extract the data from the `Try` or compose methods on it:

```
findByEmail("my@mail.com") match {
  case Success(user) => // do stuff
  case Failure(exception) => // handle exception
}
```

Or if you want to compose methods:

```
// If the Try[User] is a Failure it will return it, otherwise executes the function.
findByEmail("my@mail.com").map { case user => // do stuff }
```

Another option as @Reactormonk wrote in the comments is to use [doobie](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie) which is a functional abstraction layer over JDBC for Scala.

Comment: Using this approach it is not possible to distinguish a missing user from a failed query.

Comment: @senjin You could further pattern match the corresponding `Exception` type. I agree that using `Either[A, B]` would allow more flexibility here, i.e. use an ADT for the error side.